# TestNG exception when running from Maven

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I have a suite of selenium tests divided as java classes. I have a driver script wherein, I create the testng xml suite programmatically and run it. It all works fine when invoked from eclipse or ant. I wanted to replace ant with maven and run the tests. But getting this exception.

```
[TestRunner] Running the tests in 'TestClass10' with parallel mode:false
[RunInfo] Adding method selector: org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector@6076ab2 priority: 10
ERROR::org.testng.TestNGException:
Cannot instantiate class com.prt.regressionsuite.test10.TestClass10
===== Invoked methods
TestDriver.runTestSuite()[pri:0, instance:com.prt.driver.TestDriver@5c73a7ab] 1551083435
```

POM.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.prt</groupId>
    <artifactId>B_Selenium_RC</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>B_Selenium_RC</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.prt.driver.TestDriver</mainClass>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <timestamp>${timestamp}</timestamp>
                        </systemProperty>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <datestamp>${datestamp}</datestamp>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3-standalone</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Searched online forums but could not get any solution to this. Please help on this.

Comment: Why are you trying to run integration tests with exec-maven-plugin instead with maven-failsafe-plugin ?

Comment: TestDriver is the main class in my suite. Most forums i searched suggested exec plugin to do run that.

Answer (score 0):

When tested by using testng xml and surefire plug in, it showed the actual error about a missing data file. Solved the exception after including the file.

Have to say testng exception message is not really helpful when using the "creating testng programmatically" option.